# Need a router with tech used to limit internet usage by user in internet cafes

Tags: router

I have a potential client (a normal cafe with overcrowding issues) and they want to implement as system where clients when purchasing something, get a temporary wifi password they can use for N hours. Maybe having N dependent on how much they purchased. Thus becoming an internet cafe.

I have no idea what this kind of tech is called, so googling it was a bit hard, and would like to implement something as open source as possible.

Can you give me routers models, and possible the name of the techs I should be looking for?

Tutorials are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a captive portal.

Everyone uses the same wifi and password to connect initally.

Then a separate login in screen comes up, and you could use the captive portal to rate limit them or cut them off or etc.

Comment: some routers come with this?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are looking at an authentication with a timeout.
Most wifi-routers will support Radius authentication, and possibly others.
I don't know about timeouts.

Then you would just need to setup a Radius (or other authentication) server on a computer tied into your POS system.  (This might actually be the harder issue!)

Comment: Radius authentication. Going to check it.